# Merge (or synonymize) [facade] and [facade-pattern]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

While browsing Stack Overflow, I noticed a question which was tagged both [facade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facade) (152 questions) and [facade-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facade-pattern) (60 questions).
The description of the former clearly states that "facade" refers to a design pattern. The latter has no description, but the name is rather self-explanatory. There are [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facade+facade-pattern) (10 in total) questions that use both tags.

I believe action should be taken to merge the two, though attempts to recreate the removed tag should also be dealt with - perhaps the tags are supposed to become synonyms instead? If so, I think it would be reasonable to make [facade-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facade-pattern) the primary tag, as it is more specific.